# q.promise can't catch reject response on node js

Tags: node.js, express

I have some problem with my promises, I made a promise for check deleted status, so if status is deleted, promises will be rejected, else will be resolved, but q promises not catch reject response, I have no idea what's wrong, this is my code

```
//Promises

function checkDeleted(status){
   // 'status' return 0 or 1
   var deleted = 1
   var notDeleted = 0

   return Q.promise(function (resolve, reject){
      console.log("check deleted executed")
      if (status == notDeleted){
         console.log('Deleted Status: ' + status)
         resolve(status)
      } else {
         console.log("Else executed") // if i try to update data that has been deleted, it will be executed, actually this already executed after i am try to update data
         reject(new Error("Data has been deleted"))
      }
   })
}

//Handler
function updateTodo(req, res){
   Todo.findById(req.params.id, function (err, response){
      if (!err){
         checkDataValidated(response)
         .then(checkDeleted(response.deleted)) //this should be return reject response
         .then(dataUpdate(response, req))
         .then(saveDataUpdated(response))
         .then(function (data){
            res.json({"data":"all data already updated"})
         })
         .catch(function (error){
            res.send(error)// But reject response not catch here
         })
         .done()
      }
   })
}
```

Comment: You need to rewrite this to `.then(() => checkDeleted(response.deleted))` for example. Otherwise you're just calling all of the functions as soon as the callback to `findById` runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the way you have written your code, all of the functions run immediately when the `.findById` callback completes. You need to make these into closures like `() => checkDeleted(response.deleted)`.

I would also suggest you rewrite this to use `async`/`await` since it's easier to reason about:

```
async function updateTodo(req, res) {
   const response = await Todo.findById(req.params.id);
   try {
     await checkDataValidated(response);
     // This will throw an error if it rejects
     await checkDeleted(response.deleted);
     await dataUpdate(response, req);
     const data = await saveDataUpdated(response);
     res.json({"data":"all data already updated"});
   } catch (error) {
     res.send(error);
   }
}
```

Comment: 'All of the functions run immediately when the .findById callback completes'. Actually i don't understand with this part, Catch Handle any error from all function above right??, function checkDeleted already return rejected exception, but why catch didn't get it? All of the functions run immediately should not matter right?